# Is there a way of extracting indices from a pandas DataFrame based on value

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DataFrame:

```
index col0 col1 col2
0     0    1    0
1     1    0    1
2     0    1    1
```

I would like to extract the following indices(those that contain ones(or any value)):

```
[(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2,2))]
```

Is there a method in pandas that can do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `np.where` + `zip`

---

```
[*zip(*np.where(df))]
```

```
[(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way

```
df.columns=np.arange(df.shape[1])
df.stack().loc[lambda x : x==1].index.tolist()
[(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [numpy.nonzero](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html):

```
result = list(zip(*np.nonzero(df.values)))
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
```